# ipvsadm - How to display hostname and port?

Tags: linux, load-balancing

The output of ipvs rules in the above example one is as follows:

```
[root@penguin sbin]# ipvsadm -ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.0.8 (size=65536)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  207.175.44.110:80 rr
  -> 192.168.10.5:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> 192.168.10.4:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> 192.168.10.3:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> 192.168.10.2:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> 192.168.10.1:80              Masq    1      0          0
```

I only wanna display hostname and port (not IP and port). Example:

```
IP Virtual Server version 1.0.8 (size=65536)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  207.175.44.110:80 rr
  -> webserver-01:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> webserver-02:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> webserver-03:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> webserver-04:80              Masq    1      0          0
  -> webserver-05:80              Masq    1      0          0
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> I use `ipvsadm -ln` and I only wanna display hostname not IP

You do realise that you're explicitly instructing [`ipvsadm`](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Ipvsadm) to display the numeric ip-address rather than a hostname, right?

**`-n, --numeric`**

```
          Numeric output.  IP addresses and port numbers will  be  printed
          in  numeric  format  rather  than  as as host names and services
          respectively, which is the  default.
```